# Keras model save and load: ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, keras, save, tf.keras

System information
Have written custom code: Yes
OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10
Mobile device: No
TensorFlow installed from: conda install tensorflow
TensorFlow version: 2.1.0 (CPU only)
Python version: 3
Describe the current behavior
I train a TF Keras model (summary below) and use it for slot classification and it works fine.

I then save it using: `tf.saved_model.save(joint_model, 'BERT2.tf')`
I then load the model: `bertmodel = tf.keras.models.load_model('BERT2.tf', compile=False)`
It is compiled using the same arguments as saved model.
And then try predictions using the same function as before but I getting the following error: ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Describe the expected behavior
I run prediction using the same function but the loaded model gives the error.
I tried installing the nightly tensorflow build but was not successful.

Standalone code to reproduce the issue
Provide a reproducible test case that is the bare minimum necessary to generate
the problem. If possible, please share a link to Colab/Jupyter/any notebook.
Model:

Training:

```
joint_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses, metrics=metrics)
history = joint_model.fit(encoded_train, slot_train, epochs=15, batch_size=32)

Function for predictions:

def show_predictions(text, tokenizer, model, slot_names):
```

Other info / logs Include any logs or source code that would be helpful to
diagnose the problem. If including tracebacks, please include the full
traceback. Large logs and files should be attached.

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, 8), dtype=int32)
  Keyword arguments: {'training': False}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * {'attention_masks': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/attention_masks'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}
  Keyword arguments: {'training': False}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * {'attention_masks': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_masks'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')}
  Keyword arguments: {'training': False}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * {'attention_masks': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/attention_masks'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs/input_ids')}
  Keyword arguments: {'training': True}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * {'attention_masks': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_masks'), 'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')}
  Keyword arguments: {'training': True}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way I was saving and loading the model as suggested by someone in the TF forums. Instead of model.save(), I saved the weights and then loaded the model as per guidelines in Part II-Approach 1 here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize.
Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use weight saving and loading. Before loading weight, need to construct the model, if this is a subclassed model, needs to be built first, so that it knows the shape of input data

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#best_practice_deferring_weight_creation_until_the_shape_of_the_inputs_is_known